# Check if class has member variable?

Tags: java, class, class-members

I have written a small program, in it a couple of defined classes. I am writing tests for these classes. The constructor I wrote for one of the classes has an argument that is an instance of another class. So, it looks something like this:

```
interface type1 {}
interface type2 {}

class class1 implements type1{
    String something;
    int somethingElse;
    //...
}

class class2 implements type1{
    String something2;
    int somethingElse2;
    //...
}

class class3 implements type2{
    Object obj1;
    Object obj2;
    String blabla;
    //...

    class3(Object inObj1, Object inObj2, String x){
        this.obj1 = inObj1;
        this.obj2 = inObj2;
        this.blabla = x;
    }
}
```

As stated above, I am creating tests. There are two test classes (one for each interface). I want them to look something like this:

```
class ExamplesType1{
    class1 type1Something1 = new class1(...);
    class2 type1Something2 = new class2(...);

}

class ExamplesType2{
    class3 type2Something = new class3(type1Something1, type1Something2, ...);
}
```

My question is, how do I access the objects that are members of ExamplesType1 from ExamplesType2 so that I may... run my tests? Assume that I cannot test both interfaces in the same class, and that I cannot define once more the objects defined in ExamplesType1, in ExamplesType2.

I know I can create a return function (for example, getType1Something()), but they are public, so shouldn't I be able to access them without defining a function?

Sorry if this is a newb question... just started Java today.

Thank you for your help! If any clarification is needed, let me know.

Comment: Would be better if you follow the naming convention for the name of the classes and interfaces. According to Oracle:
"Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized."

Comment: You would have to create an instance of `ExamplesType1` before you can get to the public fields. You really should use a getter method though.

Comment: There are no public members in your code.

Comment: @4castle I agree with you, I should. But I cannot... this is a school assignment with some retarded requirements. Creating an instance would probably work... cannot see why they (TAs) would take points off. Thanks.

Comment: [Access level modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) determine whether other classes can use a particular field or invoke a particular method.

Answer (score 1):

Assume `ClassA` has two instantiated classes, `ClassB` and `ClassC` as instantiated by

```
ClassB classB = new ClassB();
ClassC classC = new ClassC();
```

`ClassB` and `ClassC` `public` variables can then be referenced inside `ClassA`, for example: `classB.variableName`.

This can reference any object that is `public` from primitive types to objects.

If the classes are not instantiated, then the `public` variables must additionally use the `static` keyword to be referenced. This `static` reference allows you to circumvent the encapsulation from a parent class and instantiation.

In other words, `ClassB` can reference the parent class, `ClassA` to retrieve a `public static` instance of itself, but if it is not a `static` variable, it must rely on instantiation, static getter methods, or instantiation with getter methods to access those objects.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have two classes

```
class ClassA {
    String flag;
    ...
}

class ClassB {
    String flag;
    ...
}
```

Them you have a few options to access field member from these classes.

1. The usually recommended method is to create setters and getter for the fields. This way any block holding a reference to an instance of those classes will be able to access and modify these fields.
2. You can also elect to make these fields public, which will also allow any block of code holding references to these classes to access the public fields.
3. If you want some classes to have access to those fields, but not everyone (not public) you can make them package protected. This will allow any other class within the same package to access those fields, but not anyone else. To make a field (or method) package protected, you simply do not specify an access modifier (public or private) for the field in question. You can read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).
4. Lastly, and very handy for testing, is to use reflection to access the private members. Reflection is not very performant, and kind of hackish, but it can be very handy in certain situations. I have mostly used reflection to mock objects in unit tests, but have seen it used in very interesting ways as well.

   Field field = MyClass.getDeclaredField("fieldName");
   field.setAccessible( true );
   String flag = field.get( myInstance );

PS> Writing this mostly from memory, but I believe this should get you going.

Hope this helps! Good luck!